# Can an electric field shift the magnetic saturation point?

Tags: electrostatics, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, magnetostatics

If we expose a magnetisable body to a strong external magnetic field, the generated magnetic field of this body is subject to saturation. If this body is now also subjected to a static electrical voltage, does the saturation point change?